# React Context - Use Provider with context like ContextName.Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am creating a context with typescript.

```
export const UserContext = createContext<
  { user: User; onChangeUser: (userId: string) => void } | undefined
>(undefined);
```

When creating the provider that will collect the child elements as a prop, the following error appears

```
export function UserProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // this error: Cannot find namespace 'UserContext'.
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        onChangeUser: (userId: string) => {
          setUserData(userId);
        },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you import `UserContext`?

Comment: yes, it's all in the same file

Comment: And you're working in a `.tsx` file?

Comment: the .tsx extension was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your file needs the `.tsx` extension instead of `.ts`.

In a `.ts` file, TypeScript will count `<Type...>` expressions as you trying to cast the following expression to the `Type...` type, instead of handling it as a JSX expression.